# What's the best way to change the size of the text in the NSView when resizing?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am working on a custom view which includes some text inside. When I resize the NSView, what's the best way to change text size according to the change of nsview? I'a thinking to have a NSImage for back storing and write everything in that image, then copy that image to the view. But I think the text will look ugly when I resize the view to very small or big, right?